# Webpack doesn't render sass correctly when not exporting file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass

I am trying to configure Webpack 4 to use Sass for a MERN project. When I use *mini-css-extract-plugin* and export a CSS file and then link it in the index.html file it works. However, when I try to bundle the css with the bundle.js file, it will not render the css and the odd thing is, it does not render just some parts of it. I tried following the official bootstrap webpack installation, but it did not work as intended.

Here are the files:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
// const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
module.exports = {
  entry: './client/src/index.js',
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader'
          },
        ],
      },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        },
        {
          test: /\.jsx$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

**./client/src/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import 'bootstrap';
import '../sass/style.scss'
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I bealive that webpack 4 support `MiniCssExtractPlugin` , the other loaders that are you trying to use dont work correctly .

Check de Docs and try it :

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/